# Cannot find file 'TracingConfig.xml' in the application xap package | WP7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, exception

I am developing a streaming application which streams video from a server.
I use SMF player to stream the video.
THe streaming happens from an SMIL file in the IIS Server.

I am getting the exception "Cannot find file 'TracingConfig.xml' in the application xap package" when i play the video.

Kindly help me get rid of this error.

Comment: SSME (that SMF uses) can through such in the debugger if you have it set to break on CLR exceptions as they occur (see CTRL+D,E button combination in Visual Studio). Can turn off that setting in the exceptions dialog. Similar error is thrown for Config.xml

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading your xml from IsolatedStorage area, make sure to use IsolatedStorageFileStream instead of general IOStream classes.

Answer (score 0):

see a workaround at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7e1fa914-c062-41de-8712-b50eca31b2d9/cannot-find-file-tracingconfigxml-in-the-application-xap-package?forum=wpdevelop on a TracingConfig.xml you could add to the root of your app's XAP (by setting Build Action=Content for that file and putting it at the root of your app's project)